# How to write in the middle of a file (Bourne Shell script)

Tags: linux, shell, sed, replace

I have some kind of database file :

```
key1 val1
key2 val2
key3 val3
...
```

I'd like to write "hello" instead of val1

What I tried to do :

```
while read line
do
    var= cut -d ' ' -f 1
    if [ $var == "key1" ]
    then
        ????
    fi
done < myfile
```

Is there a way to use FD redirections ? (Or an echo if there is some kind of offset ?...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple replacements use `sed`:

```
sed 's/val1/hello/' file
```

This will replace the first instance of `val1` on each line with `hello` if `val1` appears multiple times on a single line the add the global flag `g` like:

```
sed 's/val1/hello/g' file
```

The default behavior of `sed` is to print to `stdout` so to save the changes to a new file use redirection:

```
sed 's/val1/hello/g' file > newfile
```

or use the `-i` option of `sed` to save the changes in the original file:

```
sed -i 's/val1/hello/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a shell solution:

```
while read key val ; do
    if [ "$key" == key1 ] ; then
        val=hello
    fi
    echo "$key $val"
done < myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called an 'associative array', also known as a 'hash' in Perl, or a 'Key-value store' or 'dictionary-lookup'. The Bourne shell doesn't support them directly. Awk, Perl and Bash all have associative arrays. There are ways of hacking together associative arrays in the bourne shell, but they're ugly. Your best bet is a) pick a language better suited to the task at hand or b) if you must use the bourne shell, write a wrapper function around the associative array in a more capable language (this is essentially what sudo_O is doing with sed).

```
#! /bin/sh

lookup() {
    perl -e '%hash = ( "key1" => "hello", "key2" => "val2", "key3" => "val3" );          
             print $hash{ $ARGV[0] }
            ' $1
}

x=$(lookup "key1")
echo $x
```

This is less portable than pure bourne shell, but if you have perl available, it's a far easier route.

If you don't have perl to use in a wrapper, your best bet would be awk -- it's essentially available on any machine which has sed, and it has first class support for associative arrays.